# php date() function print formatted date

Tags: php, date, date-formatting

I would like to print a date format like: `Sun, 08 Mar 2015 14:54:54`
I use the function `date("r");` but the output is: `Sun, 08 Mar 2015 14:54:54 +0100`
how to remove part `+0100`?

Comment: An RFC2822 formatted date always includes the timezone offset.... just use `date('D, d M Y H:i:s')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [the right parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
echo date('D, d M Y H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and it's that easy:

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format("D, d M Y H:i:s");
```

Output:

```
Sun, 08 Mar 2015 15:00:57
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following.

```
// set the default timezone to use. Available since PHP 5.1
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('D, d M Y G:i:s');
// Prints something like: Sun, 08 Mar 2015 14:30:10
```

Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: OP wants: `Sun, 08 Mar 2015 14:54:54`, your output is: `Sunday 8th of March 2015 03:07:46 PM`, hmm almost!

Comment: @Rizier123 , thanks for mentioning; format changed. Now it prints like Sun, 08 Mar 2015 14:30:10 .